# WCSession sendMessage not working

Tags: xcode7, apple-watch, watchos-2, ios-app-extension, wcsession

I'm calling this code in my Watch extension (and it does run, checked with a breakpoint):

```
 [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:@{
              @"load": @"main"
              } replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
                  ...
                  }
              } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                  ...
              }];
```

In my parent app, I've got:

```
if([WCSession isSupported]){
    NSLog(@"Apple Watch detected, activated watch deletage.");
    [WCSession defaultSession].delegate = self;
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

The above code runs when the app is launched, and I've implemented:

```
-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull))replyHandler{
    ...
}
```

But it is never called. I've once got it to work, but now, I can't debug my Watch app and iOS app together properly (they don't launch, timeout etc), I deploy them one after other. When I'm debugging Watch extension, I can see the `sendMessage...` method is called (and after a few minutes, my error handler is called with a timeout error), so no issue there. When I launch my main app, I also see that `WCSession` related code is being hit. However, when I launch my Watch app to communicate with it, `didReceivedMessage...` is never called.

I've deleted my app from both iPhone and Watch, restarted both devices, and restarted my Mac and tried again, but no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Watch is not really reliable, it was a simple memory allocation issue in my case. I wasn't holding a strong reference to my `WCSession`'s delegate, and it was getting deallocated before the method was called. I've created a strong reference and the problem went away.